# Problem with monthly data on yfinance for Python

Tags: python, yfinance

I am having a problem downloading monthly data for any ticker (or list of tickers). The dates in the index of the result show more than just the beginning of the month.

Example :

```
import yfinance as yf
y_params = {
    'tickers': 'AAPL',
    'start': '2020-01-01',
    'end': '2022-11-01',
    'interval': '1mo'
}
data = yf.download(**y_params)['Adj Close']
```

The result I get for data is :

```
Date
2020-01-01     75.805000
2020-02-01     66.951164
2020-02-07           NaN
2020-03-01     62.428360
2020-04-01     72.128082
2020-05-01     78.054482
2020-05-08           NaN
2020-06-01     89.801064
2020-07-01    104.630051
2020-08-01    127.060638
2020-08-07           NaN
2020-08-31           NaN
2020-09-01    114.239166
2020-10-01    107.383446
2020-11-01    117.435234
2020-11-06           NaN
2020-12-01    131.116058
2021-01-01    130.394714
2021-02-01    119.821625
2021-02-05           NaN
2021-03-01    120.881424
2021-04-01    130.094742
2021-05-01    123.315880
2021-05-07           NaN
2021-06-01    135.767838
2021-07-01    144.590378
2021-08-01    150.508408
2021-08-06           NaN
2021-09-01    140.478470
2021-10-01    148.718552
2021-11-01    164.106659
2021-11-05           NaN
2021-12-01    176.545380
2022-01-01    173.771454
2022-02-01    164.167221
2022-02-04           NaN
2022-03-01    173.823639
2022-04-01    156.940002
2022-05-01    148.169693
2022-05-06           NaN
2022-06-01    136.304245
2022-07-01    162.015808
2022-08-01    156.741913
2022-08-05           NaN
2022-09-01    137.971115
2022-10-01    153.086044
Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64
```

You see I have a lot of NaN for apparently random dates.
Am I doing something wrong or this is a bug ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have tried your assignment. Successfully got output of only first of month data. is your version of yfinance up to date? I got results with the latest version 0.1.87.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo Finance generate a special record each time there is a split or a dividend payment.
In your data, we see a NaN every 3 months. That's a dividend entry. Other NaN are probably splits.
You can't see the amounts because you only look at one column ('Adj Close').
I can't provide more details because last time I looked at yfinance was 10 years ago.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I see your point, but that's kind of unsettling. I can't use a simple dropna() because I actually want to use this for multiple downloads and the NaN lines are different for each ticker. I though the application should have adjusted that since Action is set to "False" by default.

Comment: Suggestion: display all columns and verify if you can identify the dividend payments and eliminate those lines. Same way for splits.

Comment: That's why it's named 'adjClose'. It includes effect of splits and dividends are deducted.

Comment: Or (maybe?) remove all lines where amounts in 'Close' and 'AdjClose' are differents. But you should check with actual data.

Comment: Displaying all columns doesn't help, because the whole DataFrame is ruined with the extra lines added. So all columns have the NaN in several lines. 

Removing all lines would require an extra work using a for loop which is not really the ideal solution here for a big database. And I can't just use .dropna() because the securities will have different histories and it would remove important information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this issue has been solved by yfinance after version 0.1.87.
It now downloads correctly properly adjusting for NaN values.